# System of inequalities with 3 variables

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a system of inequalities:

\begin{array}{c}
a-b+c>0 \\ 
a+b+c<4 \\ 
9a-3b+c<-5
\end{array}

[Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a-b%2Bc%3E0;+a%2Bb%2Bc%3C4;+9a-3b%2Bc%3C-5) says that \begin{array}{c} a < -\frac {1}{8} \end{array}
But how can I solve this system of inequalities for this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Since $a+c>b$ we get $2b<4$ so $b<2$.

Also $$9a-3b+c = (a+c)+8a-3b>8a-2b$$ so we get $$8a<2b-5<4-5=-1$$

and thus the claim.

Answer (score 1):

Using the first equation, we can easily determine that :

$a+c>b\qquad\color{blue}{(1)}$

In the second equation, if we use $\,(1)\,$ we will reach the conclusion that     $\,2b<4\,$ as, $\,b+b<a+b+c<4\,$.

Therefore $\;b<2\qquad\color{blue}{(2)}$

Now in the $\,3^\text{rd}$ equation we observe
$8a-3b+b<8a-3b+a+c<-5\quad$ (using $\;(1)\;$)

So, $\;8a-2b<-5$

But, $\;b<2\quad(2)$

Therefore $\;8a-4<-5$

and hence $\;8a<-1\;.$

Answer (score 0):

Solving the system

$$
\cases{
a-b+c=s_1^2\\
a+b+c-4=-s_2^2\\
9a-3b+c+5=-s_3^2
}
$$

we obtain the solutions

$$
\cases{
a=-\frac 18-\frac 18(2s_1^2+s_2^2+s_3^2)\\
b=2-\frac 12(s_1^2+s_2^2)\\
c=\frac 18(17+6s_1^2-3s_2^2+s_3^3)
}
$$

so we can conclude easily that

$$
a < -\frac 18, \ \ b < 2
$$